# How to deny access from parent folder to child folder, but still let child folder be accessed directly?

Tags: .htaccess, security

I'm setting up some domains on a hosting account I recently purchased and the way the hosting service works is it has a main domain, and then lists the other domains on the account or 'addon' domains as subfolders to the main domain.

So I have `maindomain.com` which I want to protect, noindex, no follow, only accessible by password etc, but `maindomain.com/anotherdomain` is really `anotherdomain.com` which is fine to be accessible by anyone. Is there a way I can deny access to `maindomain.com/anotherdomain` while still allowing direct access to `anotherdomain.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can deny access to maindomain.com/anotherdomain while still allowing direct access to anotherdomain.com?

You can have this rule in doc root .htaccess of maindomain.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to check your Apache's error.log to see what the error is.

Comment: Yeah, took me a bit to find it, it's `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probably configuration error`.

Comment: There is no internal redirect in this rule. Do you have any existing rule rule already? If yes then post your current .htaccess in the question.

Comment: Well I don't, but I'm using a hosting service, maybe they have something else in the background?  `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} slabadmin\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to do anything

Comment: In that case I suspect there is some other rule causing it because my suggested is just blocking (it is not even rewriting)